# Draw a Line on Price Bars from Indicator

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

Is it possible to Draw a Line on the price bars from an indicator that is in its own panel?  Think adding a MACD indicator and when MACD conditions are met draw a line on the price bars. I am trying to avoid using a second iteration of the indicator with overlay=true to accomplish this.

If it is possible can you post the solution?

[Chart with explanation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2xGBU.png)

Comment: Yes, you can use plotcandle() and line.new()  functions.

Comment: I am stuck on stupid.  Can you elaborate.  To keep it simple, when the MACD cross below zero draw a Line on the Price Bars at he highest price while MACD was above Zero.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use `macd` indicator on the main chart, you can define some input value, and then in the indicator settings choose name of plot of the desired indicator

```
//@version=5
indicator("My Script", overlay  = true)

histogram = input(close)  

if histogram < 0
    line.new(bar_index, high, bar_index + 10, high)  // some line.new logic
```

[image]